# Gfortran compile Error: Logicals at (1) must be compared with .eqv. instead of ==

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am compiling a fortran code using Gfortran. I never had these compile errors using Intel fortran compilers. The Gfortran compiler is complaining about the use of "==" for if statement comparisons. Specifically, it gives the error

```
Error: Logicals at (1) must be compared with .eqv. instead of ==
```

Can someone explain why Gfortran requires .eqv. usage instead of ==?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gfortran is complaining because that's what Standard Fortran requires - equality of logical variables should be tested via .eqv. . The reason the Intel compiler is not complaining is because by default it doesn't compile for standard Fortran, but rather standard Fortran with some extensions which are specific to Intel Fortran. These extensions are not guaranteed to be supported by other compilers. Testing for equality of logicals with  == is one of these extensions, and it so happens gfortran doesn't support it. I strongly recommend you modify your code to use the standard method, and also look up the appropriate compiler flags so that you only use standard Fortran in future.

Comment: ifort has the -stand compile flag to warn about such usage, including other ways in which character and integer are treated as interchangeable.

Comment: I wrote about this in 2000 - https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/275071#comment-1548435